# How to find products without upsell maintained in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

When starting the Woocommerce onlineshop not every product had upsell products maintained. Now with hundreds of products, how can I find out which ones dont have the upsell maintained? Because now the customer wants to maintain those as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "upsell maintained"?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking to bulk edit the Upsell values for multiple products and see which ones are missing. WooCommerce does not have a way to achieve this by default I'm afraid. I recommend looking into CSV Import/Export type plugins to help with this. For example [CSV Import Suite](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-csv-import-suite/).